# Oracle Entity Data Model(ODP.NET)

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

We are trying to create an Entity Data model (edmx) file using Database first approach for Oracle Db.( We already have a running version of edmx for SQL Server).

Installed ODP.NET package which includes Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.dll in Visual studio 2017 for Framework 4.5 via Nuget Packages
Manually modified the connection string for Oracle as

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FacetsDataModel"
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityDataModel.csdl|res://*/EntityDataModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.OracleClient;provider connection string=”Data Source=***;User Id=**;Password=***;”;" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

The above approach didn't work because we found out that we are missing ODP.Net Managed Provider in the system. So we tried installing ODT Tools for Visual Studio 2013(didn’t work) uninstalled the same and installed 2017(still the same issue)

We found out that we missed ODAC (Oracle Data Access Components), so we installed the same but still, we didn't get the ODP.Net Managed Data Provider.

We checked the machine.config file from the below path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config

When we tried searching for a solution, we got the below link ODP.NET Managed - Unable to find requested.Net Framework Data Provider

Point 11 -- They have mentioned modifying the machine.config file by including ODP.NET, Managed Driver Under section. After modifying the machine.config file, our visual studio got crashed.

As mentioned in the link, we checked with Registry key file and check if RegKey exists or not.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\odp.net.managed

A managed ODP.NET driver does not show up in Data Source dialogue

But in our system, there is no such folder exists named AssemblyFoldersEx in the specified path.

Comment: Have a look at these Registry entries: `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\DataProviders`, `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\DataSources`, `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\DataProviders`, `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\DataSources` (the version 11.0 means Visual Studio 2012, so you have to adapt) However, I have no idea to manually add anything.

Comment: Perhaps the "ODAC for Visual Studio xxxx" from Oracle [Oracle Data Access Components - .NET Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html) works better than the Nuget package.

Answer (score 0):

You missed several information, for example what is in your config file `machine.config`. Also you did not provide us any error message. Statements as "The above approach didn't work" are not very helpful.

Anyway I will try to give you some hints:

- ODAC (Oracle Data Access Components) is a collection of various providers (ODP.NET managed and unmanaged, ODBC, OLE DB). Perhaps you selected the wrong component while installation.

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\odp.net.managed` is not used anymore. Usually the installation script should have deleted it. You Registry should look like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\AssemblyFoldersEx\ODP.Net]
@="c:\\oracle\\product\\12.2\\odp.net\\bin\\2.x"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\ODP.Net]
@="c:\\oracle\\product\\12.2\\odp.net\\bin\\4"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess]
@="c:\\oracle\\product\\12.2\\odp.net\\managed\\common"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework6]
@="c:\\oracle\\product\\12.2\\odp.net\\managed\\common\\EF6"
```

Of course you have to set folders according to your system.

Comment: Thanks for the info.Will try to re install ODAC

Comment: Hi Wernfried,We have reinstalled ODAC and now able to see the regedit entries and machine config has "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" added too.Still we are not seeing the provider listed in Visual studio.What could be the reason?